# Add an existing Progressbar into an GUI

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

I have writen an simple GUI for my command to display. When i press a button my script searches for matches in a Log File and while doing that it displays a Progressbar, but it only displays it in the ISE Window not in the GUI itself. How can i Display it in the GUI.

I found New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar when searching for a way.
But in the examples i only found how they do new Bars not add existings that only exist inside of a Button.

This is my Script

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

#Dropdown/Serverauswahl
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Select a Computer'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,400)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,240)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,46)
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(300,240)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,46)
$cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(560,40)
$label.Text = 'Please select a Server:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,80)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(540,40)
$listBox.Font = "courier New, 13"
$listBox.Height =150

[void] $listBox.Items.Add('LNS5')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('LNS10')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('LNS13')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('LNS14')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('LNS62')

$form.Controls.Add($listBox)

$form.Topmost = $true

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $x = $listBox.SelectedItem
    $path = "C:\temp\SMTPFilter\${x}filter.txt"
}

#zweites Fenster   
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1200,800)
$objForm.Text = "Test GUI"

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,600)
$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)

#Filtern
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,112)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,92)
$OKButton.Text = "Filtern"
$OKButton.Name = "Filter"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::None
$OKButton.Add_Click({$i= 0
$length = (Get-Content $path).Length

$global:result = Get-Content $path | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]'){
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            IP       = $matches[2]
            Messages = [int]$matches[3]
            Date     = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
        }}

        $i++
    if($i % 1000 -eq 0){
        Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)
    
 }}

 Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)

 #Messages Counted
 $global:cumulative = $result | Group-Object -Property IP | ForEach-Object {

    try {
        $dns = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($_.Name).HostName
    }
    catch { 
        $dns = 'Not available' 
    }

    [PsCustomObject]@{
        IP = $_.Name
        Messages = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Messages -Sum).Sum
        DNSName = $dns
        Date    = ($_.Group | Sort-Object Date)[-1].Date
    }
 }})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

#Ergebnis Anzeigen
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,214)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,92)
$OKButton.Text = "Ergebnis anzeigen"
$OKButton.Name = "Egebnis Button"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::None
$OKButton.Add_Click({$objTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox1.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(360,10) 
$objTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,600)
$objTextBox1.Text = $cumulative | Out-String
$objTextBox1.Font = "courier New, 13"
$objTextBox1.Scrollbars = "Vertical"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox1)
#outgridview
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,316)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,92)
$OKButton.Text = "Ergebnis in GridView"
$OKButton.Name = "GridView"
$OKButton.DialogResult = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$cumulative | Out-GridView})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
#Export CSV
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,418)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,92)
$OKButton.Text = "Export CSV (in C:/temp)"
$OKButton.Name = "CSV"
$OKButton.DialogResult = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$cumulative | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\SMTPresult.Csv'})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton) })
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton) 

     [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: If you want to run your PowerShell process (`$global:result = Get-Content ...`) and your progress bar simultaneously, you need  to make your script event driven (see: [How to handle progress bar using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58147372/1701026)) or even multithreading (see: [PowerShell: Job Event Action with Form not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40808521/1701026))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ProgressBar control available which you can use:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
```

See https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/02/18/progress-bar-to-a-graphical-status-box.aspx for an example

There is also a way of displaying a progressbar inside the taskbar button but you need to deploy a dll from the  Microsoft WindowsAPICodePack so that it's available to the person running the script. If you're interested I'll dig out the details